# Unable to upload image/file when using Jmeter HTTP Proxy server

Tags: jmeter

I have a Image Upload scenario to be perf. tested using Jmeter.

**Using Jmeter**

- Steps:

  1. Launched Jmeter2.9
  2. Added HTTP server to the Workbench, port 8080
  3. Set the IE Network settings to Proxy, port 8080 and localhost
  4. Launched xyz.aspx web page
  5. Logged into the application
  6. Clicked on upload image and selected the Image
- Observation:
  The Image is not getting uploaded

**Without using Jmeter**

- Steps:

  1. Launched xyz.aspx web page.
  2. Logged into the application.
  3. Clicked on upload image and selected the image.
- Observation:
  An alert message popped up and when clicked on Retry, the image got uploaded.

Alert message says `To display the web message again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted`.

Can someone please help me to continue further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the type to Java in HTTP Request defaults