# File upload fails during recording using JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I attempted to record a file upload in JMeter, using port 8888, but the file failed to upload when using JMeter as the proxy ( Recording Controller and HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder ).  I also tried to run this from within JMeter by choosing "Start" and viewing what I had just recorded in the View Results Tree listener.  When I ran it this way, I received a 500 error for the file upload line in the View Results Tree listener.

So, I ran Charles network proxy while doing the file upload to see if the same thing happened.  It did not.  I was able to successfully upload the file going through the Charles network proxy on the same port 8888.

Furthermore, I took out all proxies and did the file upload successfully.

Only when I use JMeter as the proxy do I have a problem uploading the file.

In JMeter, after first running it with no changes, I then tried to change many settings like Implementation, Content Encoding, Browser-campatible headers, Retrieve All Embedded Resources, and many others to see if this would help, but it did not.

So, my gut tells me that there is a setting that is set incorrectly.

I found this post that talks about changing to use "Java" in the HTTP Request Defaults.  ( [Unable to upload image/file when using Jmeter HTTP Proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833188/unable-to-upload-image-file-when-using-jmeter-http-proxy-server) ) This did not help me though when I tried that.
I found this post also which mentions some other types of things ( [Unable to record an upload file scenario in JMeter though it is possible by manual effort with specific browser settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835541/unable-to-record-an-upload-file-scenario-in-jmeter-though-it-is-possible-by-manu) ) .  I did check the headers against Charles and they look the same.

Any ideas?

=============  Edit below is adding the test plan screen shot===============

[image: Screen shot of test plan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, I had to remove the parameters from the "Path" line and move them to the "Send Parameters With the Request:" for the line that I had the 500 error on ( the highlighted line in the screen shot I had attached above ).

In summary, here is what happened.  When I recorded the file upload with JMeter using the Recording Controller and HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, JMeter had put all of the parameters in the "Path" field for me on many of the lines that JMeter had recorded for me.  I did not even think twice about what JMeter had done automatically for me.  So, after I removed all text except "/" in the "Path" field and added each parameter one at a time under "Send Parameters With the request", I received a "200" status code on the line that had given me the problem.  I also went into all other lines and made these same changes for the parameters.  I still am not sure if the file upload is actually working, but I don't care about that right now since I did get a "200" on the line that was giving me a problem.  That is enough progress to keep me moving ahead... :-).

Answer (score 4):

During recording you need to put the file you want to upload in jmeter/bin folder.

This is due to some limitations of browsers which do not transmit the full path.

Comment: That fixed my error on the AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd line.  But, now the /?contextKey=.... line has the 500 error still.  Before, I had to fix the AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd line manually by adjusting the File Path to find the file.  I did not have to fix that this time.  But, I am stuck at the same spot with the 500 error on the next line, which is the line with /?contextkey=....

Comment: The process in SO is to accept/upvote answer if it fixed the first issue. Then you start another question and give details, URL, Stacktrace ....

Comment: This was misleading on my part.  The original problem still exists.  I never had a 500 error on the AjaxFileUploadHandler line.  I had a file not found error.  But, I had already fixed that myself before I started this post by manually changing the file path.  I did not start this post for the file not found error.  I will definitely give you points / up votes, but should I still do that here when the original problem of the 500 error still exists?

Comment: Give more details about the response you get so that I can help, and also show your Test plan screenshot

Comment: Thread Name: Conversion Utility page 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-01-22 07:16:53 EST
Load time: 19
Latency: 19
Size in bytes: 3660
Headers size in bytes: 240
Body size in bytes: 3420
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 12:16:53 GMT
Content-Length: 3420


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

Comment: I had to remove the word "Display" from "Thread Name" in my last comment so that it would fit.  The Thread Name actually is "Display Conversion Utility" as you will see in the screen shot.  I just did not want any confusion on that since it did not look the same.