# Upload failed while using Jmeter ZK Plugin

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, zk, jmeter-plugins

I'm currently facing a problem when trying to upload a file after running the Jmeter using the zk-plugin. It works fine when uploading without running the Jmeter.

It displays a pop-up message in ZK:

```
Upload Aborted : (contentId is required)
```

Inside the Jmeter:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2015-04-16 17:35:15 SGT
Load time: 2
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2549
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2549
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.io.FileNotFoundException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: 13 4 2015.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Response headers: HTTPSampleResult fields: ContentType: DataEncoding: null
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Would be nice if you describe your deployment a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like we can only upload file that is inside our jmeter/bin. I upload using some files inside the jmeter/bin and the message is gone.

> During recording you need to put the file you want to upload in jmeter/bin folder. This is due to some limitations of browsers which do not transmit the full path.

Reference : [File upload fails during recording using JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268166/file-upload-fails-during-recording-using-jmeter) , the first answer by pmpm

Answer (score 0):

Basically ZK could return not very meaningful messages so it can be different route causes of this issues.
Look below for possible points in deployment components configuration and check they one by one:

1. First of all - check that directory pointed to by `java.io.tmpdir` exists.
   In case you use Tomcat `java.io.tmpdir` will be set to `$CATALINA_BASE/temp` by default.
   Look into catalina.sh and check that directory pointed to by `$CATALINA_TMPDIR` exists and has corresponding permissions applied:

   ```
   if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
       # Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
       CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
   fi
   . . .
   . . .
   -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
   -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
   ```
2. WEB-INF/zk.xml: `max-upload-size` value in ZK configuration descriptor (5120 Kb by default, should be enough).
3. WEB-INF/web.xml: `max-file-size` and `max-request-size` values in deployment descriptor:

   ```
   <multipart-config>
       <!-- 52MB max -->
       <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
       <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
       <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
   </multipart-config>
   ```
4. conf/server.xml: `maxPostSize` value in Connector section (the maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing):

   ```
   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443"
       maxPostSize="67589953" />
   ```